# En C#, ¿cómo se puede instanciar un objeto decidiendo los atributos con los que se éste objeto se crea?

Tags: c#, object

Dada la clase: scheduleInfo

```
public partial class scheduleInfo : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

    private double scheduledDurationField;

    private bool scheduledDurationFieldSpecified;

    private double scheduledEffortField;
}
```

Deseo generar un objeto **schedulingBeanField**

> scheduleInfo schedulingBeanField = new scheduleInfo();

Excluyendo el atributo scheduledDurationField

Comment: porque lo excluis?, lo podes dejar sin usar, ¿o que problema te genera que este incluido?

Comment: En que te beneficiaría algo así? de hecho es raro lo que planteas, podrías utilizar dos tipos de objetos que hereden de uno base pero que implementen distíntos métodos y propiedades.  Pero el mismo tipo de objeto no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al momento ya que tus 3 atributos de clase son private, no se podrá acceder a ellos desde fuera de la clase, te sugiero que los crees propiedades:

```
       public double scheduledDurationField {get; set;}
       public bool scheduledDurationFieldSpecified {get; set;}
       public double scheduledEffortField {get; set;}
```

una vez que declaras la propiedad esta no puede ser excluida ya forma parte de la clase y por ende de tu objeto, lo que si puedes realizar es lo siguiente:

```
scheduleInfo schedulingBeanField = new scheduleInfo(){scheduledDurationFieldSpecified= false, scheduledEffortField = 0.0};
```

De esa manera creas una instancia con valores para los atributos que especifiques. Pero cabe recalcar que el atributo o propiedad scheduledDurationField no es excluido de la clase ya que se inicializa con un valor de 0.0.

Comment: La recomendación es seguir usando de forma privada los atributos y accedes a ellos mediante getters y setters